# Configuring LocalDb for HTTP Connection

Tags: sql-server, http, localdb

I would like to use a Node server to communicate with a SQL Server database. I am using the Node Seriate library and SQL Server LocalDB.

I was able to get the connection working with SQL Server Express, but I would prefer to use LocalDB. With Express, I could launch the SQL Server Configuration Manager and specify the ports that I wanted my db server to listen on. I can't find a way to do that with LocalDB. Is it possible, and if so, how would I go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LocalDB only allows local connections over named pipes, so it is not possible to use LocalDB for this scenario, you must use SQL Server Express.

Just out of interest, why do you prefer LocalDB?

Comment: I've heard that LocalDB only keeps an instance of SQL server running as long as Visual Studio is open. Once you close it, it stops the db server. With Express, however, the server is running all the time whether you're developing or not. I just liked the idea of it.

I started off using Express. Then I found out about LocalDB, and thought "Hey I should try that". Then I tried it and ran into that connection issue that you answered.